# Copy static files from one Jekyll post to published site

Tags: file, static, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I would like to copy any static file (image, PDF, etc.) found in a post folder inside `_posts` to the folder in which the HTML version of the post will be, inside `_site`.

Let's say I have this structure:

```
_posts/
  2016/
    06/
      09-so-long-cloudflare/
        2016-06-09-so-long-cloudflare-and-thanks-for-all-the-fissh.md
        cloudflare-logo.png
        performance-report-sample.pdf
```

My Jekyll settings for permalinks are:

```
# Permalinks
permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title/
```

I would like to generate the site like this:

```
2016/
  06/
    09/
      so-long-cloudflare-and-thanks-for-all-the-fissh/
        index.html
        cloudflare-logo.png
        performance-report-sample.pdf
```

I've found [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/kevinoid/3131752) that should do this, but I can't make it work. I get this error:

```
jekyll 3.1.6 | Error:  undefined method `name' for #<Jekyll::Document:0x007fb7a0892b50>
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, despite having no Ruby knowledge, I managed to build a plugin out of [this old Gist](https://gist.github.com/kevinoid/3131752)! \o/

https://nhoizey.github.io/jekyll_post_files/

I hope this will help people with the same needs.